# LWC build Title component

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, parameters

In the process of developing an lwc component that can accept values such as Title, font size and icon name during LWC configuration and the padding and margins should be same as Salesforce out of the box Titles. I'm not trying to pass values dynamically but during the setting up of the component and configuring the lwc.

Say in the below code - I want to give a value for 'displayText' during setting up the lwc on a record page. How to define input variables that can accept the value for displayText and show it.

```
<template>
   <div class="slds-page-header">
        
            <lightning-card  variant="Narrow" icon-name="standard:account">
                <h1 slot="title" class="wrap">{displayText}</h1>
            </lightning-card>
         </div>
        
  </template>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Please update your question with more details about what you've tried and why it's not working the way you expect.

Comment: These are usually done with `design attributes`. 
 https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_configuration_tags

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Design Attribute in [Lightning Web Component](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_configuration_tags) which can be used to pass the style details during LWC configuration.

Each Lightning web component folder must include a configuration file named `<component>.js-meta.xml.` The configuration file defines the metadata values for the component, including targets and the design configuration for the Lightning App Builder and Experience Builder.

Here is a basic example where Text Color and Background Color passed to the LWC as configuration attributes.

demo_Design_Attribute.html

```
<template>
    <div class="slds-page-header">
        <lightning-card variant="Narrow" icon-name="standard:account">
            <h1 slot="title" style={customStyle}>{displayText}</h1>
        </lightning-card>
    </div>

</template>
```

demo_Design_Attribute.js

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

export default class Demo_Design_Attribute extends LightningElement {
    @api displayText;
    @api textColor;
    @api backgroundColor;

    get customStyle() {
        return `background:${this.backgroundColor};color:${this.textColor}`;
    }
}
```

demo_Design_Attribute.js-meta.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>52.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
        <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
    </targets>
    <!-- Configuring the design attributes -->
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__HomePage,lightning__RecordPage">
            <property name="displayText" type="String" default="Hello World" label="Enter Display Text" />
            <property name="textColor" type="String" default="red" label="Enter Display Text Color" />
            <property name="backgroundColor" type="String" default="yellow" label="Enter Display Background Color" />
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>

</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Screenshot:
[image]